# List view with dynamic cell sizes in Xamarin.forms

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms

I am trying to create a list view which changes the height of the cell on tapped.

My Custom cell looks like

```
namespace Myapp
{
    public class MyCell:ViewCell
    { 
        public MyCell ()
        {
            Label objLabel = new Label {
                VerticalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,
                TextColor = Color.Yellow,                
            };
            objLabel.SetBinding (Label.TextProperty, new Binding ("Name"));


        StackLayout objLayout = new StackLayout {
            Padding = new Thickness (20, 0, 0, 0),
            Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            Children = { objLabel }
        };

        Frame objFrame_Inner = new Frame {
            Padding = new Thickness (15, 15, 15, 15),
            HeightRequest = 36,
            OutlineColor = Color.Accent,
            BackgroundColor = Color.Blue,
            Content = objLayout,                
        };

        Frame objFrame_Outer = new Frame {
            Padding = new Thickness (0, 0, 0, 10),
            Content = objFrame_Inner,
            HeightRequest = 50
        };

        View = objFrame_Outer;            

        //this.BindingContextChanged += MyCellBindingContextChanged;
    }

    protected override void OnBindingContextChanged()
    {
        base.OnBindingContextChanged();
        WalletCard objMenuItem = (WalletCard)this.BindingContext;
        objMenuItem.PropertyChanged += MyItemPropertyChanged;
    }

    void MyCellBindingContextChanged (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WalletCard objMenuItem = (MyItem)this.BindingContext;
        objMenuItem.PropertyChanged += WalletCardPropertyChanged;
    }

    void MyItemPropertyChanged (object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.PropertyName) {
        case "CellHeight":
            this.Height = (this.BindingContext as MyItem).CellHeight;
            this.ForceUpdateSize ();
            break;
        }
    }
}
}
```

And the ListView usage

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <DataTemplate x:Name="MyTemplate" x:Key="MyTemplate">
        <local:MyCell></local:MyCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>
<ContentPage.Content>
    <ListView HasUnevenRows="true"
                    ItemsSource = "{Binding myItems}"
                    ItemTapped="ItemTapped"
                    ItemTemplate = "{StaticResource MyTemplate}"
            />
</ContentPage.Content>
```

And on tapping of the item in list view,the CellHeight property of the corresponding item is increased.

edit

Adding Item Tapped event

```
void ItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e) {
        var selectedItem = (MyItem)e.Item;
        selectedItem.CellHeight = 200;
    }
```

/edit

The problem is when the item is tapped for the first time, the height doesn't change but it changes when tapped again after selecting different item.

Any idea how I can fix this or are any other elegant way of achieving the same.

Comment: which event are you using ItemTapped or ItemSelected ?

Comment: Item Tapped.. sorry for the wrong naming. Will update

Comment: Also your ItemTapped event, as per your question you are facing the problem when the item is selected. So please add the code for ItemTapped.

Comment: @AkashAmin Added the event handler